# Configure aws-sdk-go to interact with localstack's SQS

Tags: go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I need some help trying to integrate [aws-sdk-go](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go) with [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) to access SQS service.

I tried something like:

```
result, err := q.Client.SendMessage(&sqs.SendMessageInput{
    MessageAttributes: map[string]*sqs.MessageAttributeValue{
        "JobName": &sqs.MessageAttributeValue{
            DataType:    aws.String("String"),
            StringValue: aws.String(jobName),
        },
    },
    MessageBody: aws.String(messageBody),
    QueueUrl:    &q.URL,
})

if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
```

With an initialization like:

```
type Queue struct {
    Client sqsiface.SQSAPI
    URL    string
}

var q Queue

    func init() {
      sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }))

    q = Queue{
        Client: sqs.New(sess),
        URL:    viper.GetString("queue.sqs.url"),
    }
}
```

**How can I configure the SDK to access localstack's SQS?**

Comment: Currently the problem is even if i am giving local host url in QueueUrl attribute, still its trying to connect to https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: can you add here, implementation of `q.Client.init()` and `q.Client.SendMessage()`?

Comment: type Queue struct {
 Client sqsiface.SQSAPI
 URL    string
}

var q Queue

func init() {
 sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
  SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
 }))

 q = Queue{
  Client: sqs.New(sess),
  URL:    viper.GetString("queue.sqs.url"),
 }
}

Comment: thanks, I can see that, you are using viper(possibly https://github.com/spf13/viper this?) to read, URL. Is this  url you are connecting to when code runs?  is it stored in some config file? if so, modifying that config file(possibly a `.json`), will get you where you want to be. On the other hand, it would make things clearer if you could also paste the `SendMessage()` function.

Comment: SendMessage() is sdk function, i have verified the url its correctly pointing to localhost, the issue is even before here, while initilisation of sdk itself its throwing error

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: ERRO[0004] InvalidAddress: The address https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ is not valid for this endpoint.

Comment: i figured out the issue , need to initialise client like below

Comment: q = Queue{
  Client: sqs.New(sess, aws.NewConfig().WithEndpoint(viper.GetString("queue.sqs.url"))),
  URL:    viper.GetString("queue.sqs.url"),
 }

Comment: You need to set up `aws.Config.Endpoint = aws.String("http://localhost:localStackSQSPort")` when creating a new `SQS` session.